# Methods to authentication in an iOS app

Tags: android, ios, authentication, ios4, plc

I'm developing an iOS application for a client that reads PLC controller data via TCP/IP. The PLC devices don't have any method to authenticate a user..so basically if you know what your looking for, are on net; you have the ability to read the data and write to the registers if you want to. Well the goal with this application is to allow for some sort of Permission or authentication in the app. Example. The engineer of said devices has the ability to right to the registers but a maintenance worker only has read only permissions. There is no way of adding a authentication method to the PLC devices sitting on the LAN. I need to come up with a way of doing it through the app.

Any suggestions?

Things to keep in mind...

1: More often than not these PLC devices are NOT on a LAN that has access to the internet.

2: More often than not the iPAD/iPhone will not be able to get to the internet for any sort of web based authentication.

3: This app will also need to be developed on the Android so the authentication will need to be cross platform compatible.

4: Different clients from different companies will need the ability to "adjust" and "customize" a users permissions.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: What answers are you looking for?
Do you want to know how to do authentication on Android devices, or do you need help designing the architecture of the whole system?

Answer (score 0):

Allen Bradley has already created a very similar software platform for their PLC's called Assetcentre for OC's. I suggest you read their documentation carefully to udnerstand their architecture. In their software system the first step is to delete the PLC communications software off all the PC's and force them to connect via a special "gateway" networked version which both handles authentication/security and does the actual PC<-->PLC communication.

For "unconnected" mode, a PC "borrows" a license (downloads the security profile) which has an expiration date in it so that the file "expires".

Obviously anyone with a "rogue" PC in the plant can bypass all of this by going back to the way they used to do it.